# two table merge in single gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Having a two table

```
login
id(pk) | username | password 

bookmark
id     |Name      |image    | user_id(fk) ).
```

In c# code we need merge into a single grid view.Here is implemented my code snippets.

on pageload fill gridview

```
 public void binggrid(){
    using (sqlconnection con =new sql connection (constring){
    cmd.commandText="select b.id,b.Name,b.Image,l.username from bookmark inner join login l on b.user_id=l.id where l.id='" +login.id+"';
    cmd.connection=con;
    con.open();
    gridview.datasource=cmd.ExecuteReader();
    gridview.DataBind();
    con.close();
     }
 }
```

In designing webform aspx

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username"/>
```

Error occur if i embedded other table member .

Error show compiler:

> A field or property with the name 'username' was not found on the
>   selected data source

How to solve it? Please help.

Comment: Are you binding the gridview on pageload? Can you post some more of your ASPX, including if/where you define the datasource?

Comment: I smell SQL injection.

Comment: yes sir tyler roper binding the gridview on page load

Answer (score 0):

You missed `b` after `bookmark table` in your `sql` query. Also use `parametrized sql query` to avoid `sql injection`.

```
select b.id,b.Name,b.Image,l.username from bookmark b inner join login l on b.user_id=l.id where l.id=@LoginId
```